# Undirected connected graphs

Tags: graph, vertices

I'm confused as to whether an undirected graph can be considered connected?

For example:

A---B---C

Say that we have three vertices, A, B and C. If the graph is undirected like the one above, is it connected? A reaches B, but does it reach C?

Another example:

A--->B<---C

Am I correct to say this directed graph is not connected because A cannot reach C? Because to me it looks like this graph is not multi-directional.

Another example:

A---B
C---B

Would this undirected graph be connected?

If anyone could explain in more detail, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connected graph will mean that we can reach every node in this graph through some path. Take for example the graph below which is connected because we can reach every node in this graph

```
    0 --- 1-------5----6--8
    | \    \      |   /  /
    |  \    \     |  /  /
    |   \    \    | /  /
    2    3----4---7---9
```

However a graph like this

```
    0 --- 1-------5----6  8
    | \    \      |   /  /
    |  \    \     |  /  /
    |   \    \    | /  /
    2    3----4---7   9
```

Is disconnected because there is no way to reach 8 and 9. A simple way to check if a graph is connected is to have a boolean of visited nodes. Run bfs or dfs and whenever you are at a node, mark it at visited. When your algorithm is done running, if all vertices were not visited then your graph is disconnected.

From your example, the first graph A---B---C is connected 
Second graph A--->B<---C is disconnected because there is no path from A to C. If we ran bfs/dfs on this we cannot visited all the vertices 
Third graph A---B C---B is also disconnected as they are two separate graphs.

Comment: No problem @ChrisMulheron